# What is the meaning of CType?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code that allows me to detect changes has done to a datagridview comobobox column under the EditingControlShowing event of the datagridview
i already knows how it works except something

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, 
          ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) _
                  Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
        If (combo IsNot Nothing) Then

            RemoveHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionchangeCommitted)

            AddHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionchangeCommitted)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

What i don't understand is
= CType(e.Control, ComboBox)

what is e.control and why used CType and why all of that = combo
the whole mentioned line is not understandable for me

Comment: Have you tried looking for what CType?

Comment: `e` is a parameter of type DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs, [CType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx) tries to convert `e.Control` (a property typed to evaluate to a Control) to a ComboBox (via a cast in this case), so that it can be assigned to the variable.

Comment: It might have been faster to [consult MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @user2864740 you were too helpful,
Please add your comment as answer so i can mark it as solution

Comment: Also, think of 'CType' as being short for "convert to type".

Answer (score 0):

See [CType Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx).

> Returns the result of explicitly converting an expression to a specified data type, object, structure, class, or interface.